# Paging in ListView with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am doing paging in a `Listview` with Entity Framework and I'm stuck when passing `startindex` and `maxrows` after clicking the next/prev button

This is my code

```
private  List<WorkItem> Data(int startindex, int maxrows)
{            
       return (from x in ss.WorkItem
                    select x).OrderBy(p => p.WorkItemID).Skip(startindex).Take(maxrows).ToList();

}

protected void lvWorkItems_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
        this.DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
        lvWorkItems.DataSource = Data(e.StartRowIndex,e.MaximumRows);

        lvWorkItems.DataBind();
}
```

My problem is how to pass `startindex` and `maxrows` when I click on next/Previous button. 
Please help

Answer (score 3):

Check it out please  , it extension method :

```
 public static IQueryable<T> MyPage<T, TResult>(this IQueryable<T> obj, int    
 page,     int  pageSize, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, TResult>>  
 keySelector, bool asc, out int rowsCount)
 {
    rowsCount = obj.Count();
   if (asc)
    {
       return obj.OrderBy(keySelector).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
   else
   {
       return obj.OrderByDescending(keySelector).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
   }        
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali. In this method user how can fetch last page? think user want go to last page how i can calculate input parameters?for more information i need know total count page. and When you know that the user is viewing the last page?In this case, the user should not be able to request the next page.

Comment: There is some notations here : ListView Control (asp) dont have Paging and PageIndex Events ,and this person who asked this question didn't any things about your idea but if you keep current page index in Static variable and when final user click on Next Or Last page button , you can hadle it easy and call my Method again , also if you need call Last Page in your page you should gathering total Conunt Of your selected Item and when you Click on LastPageButton can calculate Page Of you need (TotalCount/PageSize)=page , and then Call my method.Thanks my dude...

Comment: Merci de votre réponse Ali.

Answer (score 1):

This was exactly my problem too.

But my problem was solved by changing the structure of business output class method.

And of course, in this way you need to have the data output and number of rows.

And do not forget the issue relating to the same page layout data must be fetched from the database.

My class was designed to do the following.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using Andish.CSS.Common.Enum;

using AutoMapper;

using system.linq.dynamic;


namespace Andish.CSS.Common.Result.Implementation

{

   public static class PagingResult

    {

        public static PageResult<K> ToPageResult<T, K>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, int rowCount,
            int pageNumber, string sortField, DynamicLinqSortFieldKind 

dynamicLinqSortFieldKind)

        {

var allQueryRow = queryable.ToList<T>().Count();

            var skipLen = (pageNumber - 1) * rowCount;


            string orderKind = "";

            orderKind = dynamicLinqSortFieldKind == DynamicLinqSortFieldKind.Ascending ? " Asc" : " Desc";

 PageResult<K> pageResult = new PageResult<K>

                                           {

                                               PageNumber = pageNumber,

                                               RowCount = rowCount,

                                               Result = Mapper.Map<IList<K>>(queryable.OrderBy(sortField + orderKind)
                                                                             .Skip(skipLen).Take(rowCount).ToList<T>()),
                                               ResultRowCount = allQueryRow,

                                               PageCount = allQueryRow % rowCount == 0 ? allQueryRow / rowCount : (allQueryRow / rowCount) + 1

                                           };

            return pageResult;


        }

 }



}

create this enum

public enum DynamicLinqSortFieldKind

    {

        Ascending = 0,

        Descending = 1

    }
```

And for use this extension Method do like this
and i have one result from class ExecutiveUnit and I want map this class to enother class
ExecutiveUnitModel .
i use automapper nuget.

```
var xresult = result.ToPageResult<ExecutiveUnit, ExecutiveUnitModel>(RowNumbers, pageNumber, "Code", DynamicLinqSortFieldKind.Ascending);
```